# fsck exited with status code 4 - causes?

Tags: linux, fsck

I restarted my computer (normally, through menu) on Linux Mint recently. Upon restart, the Mint splash screen showed (past the UEFI/BIOS settings menu), but then it only got a terminal with input prompt.

I had to run

```
fsck /dev/sdba2
```

and accept a bunch of fixes.

My question isn't about what to do (I figured out how to fix it on the spot and would likely be fine to do so again), but any potential causes to that? I restart with some browsers & tabs open, but as far as I can remember no crazy programs going that would be likely to cause somewhat serious disk errors.

```
Hardware: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 0 @ 3.20GHz
Harddrives: 1 tera HDD and 200 meg SDD drives (unsure of details, could check)
```

Any known/likely causes and potential prevention?

Comment: How did you "restart" the machine?

Comment: What is "200 milligramm SDD drive"? And BTW: what filesystem do you use?

Comment: Programs, generally, cannot cause filesystem corruption.  They can corrupt the content of _files_, but not the _filesystem_.